# Add block on MatLab Simulink does strange things

Tags: matlab, simulink

I did a simulation of the following circuit on **MatLab Simulink** (I will only show the section of interest):

[image]

and obtained the following results from the scope:

[image]

As you can see the add block, didn't "add" the two input signals. Instead, it subtracted the first from the second, where the first was null. So, why this happened? How could I correct this?

Comment: Looks like expected behaviour to me. What output were you hoping to get?

Comment: The first one is initially 1, and the second is 0. But the sum gave 0...

Comment: That's true. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @ÉlioPereira: That looks really strange, could you try to verify if it's really the part which you have shown to us causing the strange behaviour. Use some source block like a repeating sequence as an input for your four blocks and try to reproduce it. I tried to reproduce it but did not succeed.

Comment: Could you verify which are the [data types](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/displaying-signal-properties.html#f15-90122) of the signals? I'm suspecting the comparison returns a boolean which may have something to do with what you're seeing.

Comment: @Daniel: I connected a pulse generator to the input signals and nothing wrong happened. So the problem is really from some other part..

Comment: @mikkolam The signals are booleans. No, I'm undestanding why it gave me such stange results. Shouldn't Simulink give me some error notification?

Comment: IT's technically not an error.

Comment: @mikkolam, you solved the problem

Comment: @ÉlioPereira that's great to hear! Good luck with your circuit. :)